# Custom Visualforce Quick Actions not Visible in Salesforce1 but visible in Desktop

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app

Made a visualforce page and created a Quick Action for it - added it to the Page layout inside Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions.

Yes I can see it and use it normally in Desktop - but accessing it through Salesforce1 or Salesforce App for mobile, it is not showing the Custom Visualforce Quick Actions.

All the permissions are correctly set, its just a plain visualforce page "Hello World". What did I miss?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check: Did you enable the VF page involved for Lightning Experience? It is a checkbox on the VF page: `Available for Lightning Experience, Lightning Communities, and the mobile app`